# Loopback Model discovery from PostgreSQL error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs, loopback

I am currently building a loopback project and I need to discover existing data in a PostgreSQL database to make my models, I have successfully created the models by following the tutorial found in the docs: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Discovering-models-from-relational-databases.html#discover-and-save-model-definitions , but when I run GET method for any model I get an error that says

> relation "public.acl" does not exist

can anyone help me fix this issue, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Marvin, i solved the problem by running this auto update script in ./server/boot/migrateTables.js :

```
'use strict';

module.exports = migrateTables;

function migrateTables(server) {
  var storage = server.datasources.db;

  storage.autoupdate();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have told loopback to use your database for authentication.  Loopback is asking for a table to authenticate each request which does not exist.  This has nothing to do with auto migration.  The following is how you can easily create the tables you need.

[Loopback automigration script](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html#creating-database-tables-for-built-in-models)

> Create server/create-lb-tables.js file with the following:

```
var server = require('./server');
var ds = server.dataSources.MYDATABASE;
var lbTables = ['User', 'AccessToken', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping', 'Role'];
ds.automigrate(lbTables, function(er) {
  if (er) throw er;
  console.log('Loopback tables [' + lbTables + '] created in ', ds.adapter.name);
  ds.disconnect();
});
```

> Run the script manually:

```
$ cd server
$ node create-lb-tables.js
```